# Reorganise table structure or possible with one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one showing items users have bought from various stores, and the other which details who bought what.

Table A for products is:

```
prod_id
site_name
product
```

Table B for users is:

```
user_id
prod_id
```

I need to count the total number of products bought from a certain store. I can't simply count from Table A as there may be the same products bought by several users but to keep the data tidy I store it as above.

Should I include the site_name in table B going forward as well to make it easier to simply count that, or can it be done in one query? I'd rather not bloat tables for the sake of a couple of queries as I think that would be bad database design but cannot work out how to do the count otherwise.

Is it possible?

Comment: To me it is unclear what exactly you want to count and what entities the two tables represent. Does a site_name represent a single store?

Comment: You mean _bought from a certain store_ by a certain user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use a join:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM A JOIN B ON A.prod_id = B.prod_id
WHERE A.site_name = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from 
    A inner join B on A.prod_id = B.prod_id
where 
    site_name = 'the site name' 
    and 
    user_id = '1'
```